# Unable to modify pointer variable passed as argument to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I have this function

```
int rt_exist(struct route_entry* prev_rte) {

prev_rte = rte_head;   //This doen't assigns rte_head to prev_rte

return 0;

}
```

where **rte_head** is an initialized struct route_entry* pointer variable.
But in the above case "prev_rte" is not assigned the value of rte_head.

By the way ,I if I do something like this

```
int rt_exist(struct route_entry* prev_rte) {

struct route_entry* rte_new;
rte_new = rte_head;      //But this can 

return 0;

}
```

The above assignment occurs smoothly . The problem arises when pointer variable is passes as function argument.

It's a weird question with little details ,but can someone point me to a possible direction or something wrong I might be doing.

Comment: Change the function signature to `int rt_exist(struct route_entry*& prev_rte) {`, you are modifying a copy of that pointer local to the function only.

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? The answers are completely different for the two different languages.

Comment: Perhaps you should first learn about elementary language constructs (such as function calls and argument types) before writing programs ...

Comment: Ok, it's question of a bloody beginner, but I feel it's not a bad, abd question per se, deserving 6 downvotes ...

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. And your question is mighty unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this:

```
void foo (int j)
{
    j = 7;
}

foo (8);
```

What do you expect to happen here? A function can't change a value in the caller this way.

What should happen here:

```
rt_exist (NULL);
```

For C++, you can use references:

```
int rt_exist(struct route_entry*& prev_rte) {

prev_rte = rte_head;   //This doen't assigns rte_head to prev_rte

return 0;

}
```

For C, you need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to change:

```
int rt_exist(struct route_entry** prev_rte_ptr) {

*prev_rte_ptr = rte_head;   //This doen't assigns rte_head to prev_rte

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! in first case you are using temporary portion of a stack. But in the second case you are using allocating. Which means that you are using a portion of memory which is from heap. It will obviously affect the value. This is like a new variable in a new block. In this scope it will have the assigned value.

But in rt_exist the copy of the variable is passed. So any change in that will not affect the actual one. But you can pass it's address and change it easily like this.

```
int rt_exist(struct route_entry** prev_rte) 
{
*prev_rte = rte_head;   //This does assign rte_head to prev_rte.
return 0;
}
```